# Twitter Bootstrap with Sass in Rails Layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, layout, sass, view

I am attempting to learn Rails layouts and am trying to do so using the `bootstrap-sass` gem.

I want to add a navbar to the top of my view, as well as the side. The bars should connect fluidly, with no breaks in between the two.

I have made it as far as adding a top navbar, but now I need to add a sidebar to the left. There doesn't seem to be a "navbar left" feature within Twitter Bootstrap. How can I add a menu to the left as well as the top within my rails layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class called `navbar-left` that will left justify that component in the navbar (check out the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment)

You could also create a nav (see the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) and add the classes `nav-stacked` and `pull-left`

Hope this helps

Comment: This stuff never ceases to amaze me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [navs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) or [list groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group).
Two of many ways to go about it.

Don't forget about [.pull-left](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)!